# How can i store / re-store instances of class objects with pickle?

Tags: python, serialization, pickle

i have a long list of parameters that i would like to store to a single file for restoration later on. It seems like pickle is the module for me, but i am having difficulty storing all of the data i would like.

my intention is to create a single dictionary with all of the parameters (scalars, lists, dictionaries) which contain integers, reals, strings, class instances, etc, and dump that to pickle as follows:

```
pickle_dict = {}

pickle_dict['RunDir'] = RunDir
pickle_dict['filename_cfg'] = filename_cfg
pickle_dict['fluid_num'] = fluid_num
pickle_dict['body_num'] = body_num
pickle_dict['sleeve_matl'] = sleeve_matl
pickle_dict['ctg_matl'] = ctg_matl
pickle_dict['dowel_matl'] = dowel_matl
pickle_dict['beam_matl'] = beam_matl
#pickle_dict['MyBolts'] = MyBolts
#pickle_dict['MyScdmComps'] = MyScdmComps
pickle_dict['dowel_num'] = dowel_num
pickle_dict['beam_num'] = beam_num
pickle_dict['sleeve_num'] = sleeve_num
#pickle_dict['MyComps'] = MyComps
#pickle_dict['BN2CN'] = BN2CN
#pickle_dict['PN2CN'] = PN2CN
pickle_dict['intf_list'] = intf_list
pickle_dict['int_real'] = int_real
pickle_dict['int_type'] = int_type
pickle_dict['assy_mode'] = assy_mode
pickle_dict['coating_face_id'] = coating_face_id
pickle_dict['cooling_face_id'] = cooling_face_id
pickle_dict['mapped_face_id'] = mapped_face_id
pickle_dict['axial_div'] = axial_div
pickle_dict['slv_radial_div'] = slv_radial_div
pickle_dict['ctg_radial_div'] = ctg_radial_div
pickle_dict['circ_div'] = circ_div
pickle_dict['bolt_ndiv'] = bolt_ndiv
pickle_dict['bolt_assy_imp'] = bolt_assy_imp
pickle_dict['bolt_num'] = bolt_num

with open(filename_cfg + '.pickle', 'wb') as filename:
    pickle.dump(pickle_dict, filename)
```

I have commented out the data that doesnt "load" because it consists of lists of class instances.
My intention is to read the data back in as follows:

```
with open(filename_cfg + '.pickle', 'rb') as filename:
    pickle_dict = pickle.load(filename)

RunDir = pickle_dict['RunDir']
filename_cfg = pickle_dict['filename_cfg']
fluid_num = pickle_dict['fluid_num']
body_num = pickle_dict['body_num']
sleeve_matl = pickle_dict['sleeve_matl'] 
ctg_matl = pickle_dict['ctg_matl'] 
dowel_matl = pickle_dict['dowel_matl']
beam_matl = pickle_dict['beam_matl']
MyBolts = pickle_dict['MyBolts']
MyScdmComps = pickle_dict['MyScdmComps']
dowel_num = pickle_dict['dowel_num']
beam_num = pickle_dict['beam_num']
sleeve_num = pickle_dict['sleeve_num']
MyComps = pickle_dict['MyComps']
BN2CN = pickle_dict['BN2CN']
PN2CN = pickle_dict['PN2CN']
intf_list = pickle_dict['intf_list']
int_real = pickle_dict['int_real']
int_type = pickle_dict['int_type']
assy_mode = pickle_dict['assy_mode']
coating_face_id = pickle_dict['coating_face_id']
cooling_face_id = pickle_dict['cooling_face_id']
mapped_face_id = pickle_dict['mapped_face_id']
axial_div = pickle_dict['axial_div']
slv_radial_div = pickle_dict['slv_radial_div']
ctg_radial_div = pickle_dict['ctg_radial_div']
circ_div = pickle_dict['circ_div']
bolt_ndiv = pickle_dict['bolt_ndiv']
bolt_assy_imp = pickle_dict['bolt_assy_imp']
bolt_num = pickle_dict['bolt_num']
```

Im not sure if there is a better way of doing this... it seems like a very roundabout way. In MATLAB i would just save the workspace and have all the information there. If there is a better way to do this i'd really appreciate someone pointing me in the right direction

But as it is, right now my lines that fail, fail for the following reason:

body_ instance has no **call** method

an example of one of the parameters that fails with the above error is as follows:

BN2CN

```
{0: [<.body_ instance at 0x0000000000000B67>], 1: [<.body_ instance at 0x0000000000000B93>], 2: [<.body_ instance at 0x0000000000000BA7>], 3: [<.body_ instance at 0x0000000000000BBB>], 4: [<.body_ instance at 0x0000000000000BD0>], 5: [<.body_ instance at 0x0000000000000BE4>], 6: [<.body_ instance at 0x0000000000000BF9>], 7: [<.body_ instance at 0x0000000000000C0D>]}
```

which is just a dictionary i created to order some class instances i have.

Is there something fundamental about class instances that need to be treated differently when storing using pickle? is it simply not possible? Is there a better way to achieve what i am looking for? Ideally i would even be able to store the class definitions in pickle (if possible)..

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I would `pip install dill` and see if it works for your purpose using `dill.dump_session('filename.pkl')`

Comment: I guess i forgot to mention that i am using IronPython, and im not sure i have the ability to install additional libraries on my server. Any way to do this with Pickle itself? or some other means? Thanks alot!